# cannot use class because it is not a trait

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have followed the tutorial [here](http://culttt.com/2014/01/13/advanced-validation-service-laravel-4/) on building a validation service for laravel. I am having issues now when trying to call the validator from one of my controllers. I am seeing the error:

`validController cannot use Portal\Service\Validation\Laravel\AppInstancesValidator - it is not a trait`

here is my controller:

```
class validController extends BaseController {

   use \Portal\Service\Validation\Laravel\AppInstancesValidator;

   public function validateInstance() {
      $post = Input::all();

      $instVal = new AppInstancesValidator( App::make('validator'));

      return $instVal->with($post)->passes();
  }

}
```

and my validator:

```
namespace Portal\Service\Validation\Laravel;

use Portal\Service\Validation\ValidableInterface;

class AppInstancesValidator extends LaravelValidator implements ValidableInterface {


  protected $rules = array(
    'app_name' => 'required',
    'app_instance_name' => 'required',
    'app_instance_ip' => 'required|ip'
  );

}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try putting the `use` before the `class` declaration:

```
<?php // namespace Portal\Controllers;

use \Portal\Service\Validation\Laravel\AppInstancesValidator;

class validController extends BaseController {

    public function validateInstance() {}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your 'use' statement should be above the class definition of validController