# PHP traits - cannot use method defined in trait

Tags: php, oop, cakephp-3.0, dry, traits

I used to have several library classes with the exact same methods. Figured I'd learn a bit more about two important aspects of coding; Traits and DRY.

I have the following trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Berry;

trait Lib
{
    public function getIDs()
    {
        $oClass = new \ReflectionClass(get_called_class());
        $aConstants = $oClass->getConstants();
        foreach($aConstants as $sKey => $mValue)
        {
            if(!is_int($mValue))
            {
                unset($aConstants[$sKey]);
            }
        }
        return array_values($aConstants);
    }
}
```

The following class:

```
namespace App\Berry;

use Lib;

class postType
{
    const POST_TYPE_BLOG_ID     =   1;
    const POST_TYPE_BLOG_LABEL  =   __('blog', 'lib');

    const POST_TYPE_PAGE_ID     =   2;
    const POST_TYPE_PAGE_LABEL  =   __('page', 'lib');

    const POST_TYPE_NEWS_ID     =   3;
    const POST_TYPE_NEWS_LABEL  =   __('news', 'lib');
}
```

And am calling it like this in my `PicturesController` class:

```
$cPostTypesLibrary = new postType();
$this->set('aPostTypes', $cPostTypesLibrary->getIDs());
```

Now to me, this seems almost exactly like the tell me to do in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.multiple) example #4 (About using multiple traits)

The only difference I have is I have the `use` outside of my class due to getting [cannot use class because it is not a trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23553160/cannot-use-class-because-it-is-not-a-trait)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is not using the trait, you are instead using the [*other*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) use of the `use` keyword and trying to import the `Lib` class from the same namespace into, well, the same namespace.

To use traits correctly, go back to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php), and look at where they are placed.  The `use` statement is placed inside of the class definition. In your case, it would look like this:

```
namespace App\Berry;

class postType
{
    use Lib;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Alright so looking at the question I linked in my post I'm guessing `use` goes within the class definition when the class isn't in the same namespace?

Comment: No, you put it inside of the class definition when it is a _trait_ and you want that class to use that trait. You put it _outside_ when you want to use that _class_ inside of yours but you don't want to type the fully qualified namespace of the class every time you want to reference it.

Comment: NP, glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare the trait **inside** the class

```
class postType
{
    use Lib;
}
```