# App\Models\CardsAPI cannot use mtgsdk\Card - it is not a trait

Tags: php, laravel

When requesting https://github.com/MagicTheGathering/mtg-sdk-php my application throws an error:

`App\Models\CardsAPI cannot use mtgsdk\Card - it is not a trait`

My model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use mtgsdk\Card as SDKCard;

class CardsAPI extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SDKCard;

    public function getAllCards() {
        return SDKCard::all();
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\CardsAPI;

class CardsAPIController extends Controller
{
    use CardsAPI;

    public function index() {
        return CardsAPI::getAllCards();
    }
}
```

Does somebody has experience with this SDK error. If I basic curl it, it gives back data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot use class because it is not a trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23553160/cannot-use-class-because-it-is-not-a-trait)

Answer (score 0):

As the erorr says, you can't use the SDKCard as a [trait](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php). Instead, you need to use it as a class. Just remove the `SDKCard` from use `HasFactory, SDKCard;` in your `App\Models\CardsAPI` class.

Comment: And CardsAPIController probably cannot use CardsAPI.

Answer (score 0):

you cant use the classes as a trait. just remove **SDKCard** in your model as a trait and remove **CardsAPI** in your Controller as a trait.

kind regards